# How to do a PUT and Copy INTO Snowflake with Python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I am needing to know how to execute a PUT file and COPY INTO from Python.  I know write_pandas will write data into Snowflake directly, and does a PUT and COPY INTO behind the scenes, but how would I accomplish this myself "manually" in Python?

Just looking for a good example that stages files and copies them into an existing VARIANT column for the XML data.  When I tried write_pandas it inserted quotation marks around each row which screws up the casting of columns in Select statements later in Snowflake.  To get rid of the quotation marks I tried adding quote_identifiers=False but it still writes the data in wrapped in quotes:

```
pandasDF = pd.DataFrame(rowData)
pandasDF.columns =['DATACOLUMN']

from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas

success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(engine, pandasDF, 'OI_PNET_GET_PERFORMX_UPL2', quote_identifiers=False)
```

Here is what it looks like after insertion with starting and trailing quotes:  [image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code below

```
with stage_engine.connect() as con:
 con.execute("rm @{}.%{}".format(target_schema,table_name))
 con.execute("put file://{}* @{}.%{}".format(tmp_dir+'/test.csv',target_schema,table_name))
 con.execute("copy into {} file_format = (type = csv FIELD_DELIMITER='~' field_optionally_enclosed_by='\"')".format(full_table_name))
```

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to have an XML example?

Comment: Also, how does the COPY INTO statement know where it is getting the data from?  I just see full_table_name and am guessing that is the target table?  Should it not include the source table in that statement?  Your second statement has 3 ``` at the end which gives a syntax error.  Is there more to the 2nd statement that didn't make it into what you pasted?

Comment: Can I also see where you set up con?

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#copying-data-from-an-internal-location

Comment: You can refer this doc for the connection setup

Comment: Let me find an example for xml

Comment: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Easily-Load-XML-with-SQL-Pt-1

Comment: follow this to parse the xml content after loadinf

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll mark this a solved if you can answer a question.  I used those commands but it is inserting a strange row with an entirely different XML document, like one I ran before.  Is there some way to clear this file?

Comment: This the the code I am working with:  tmp_dir = "C:/Users/Desktop/Data"
target_schema = "PUBLIC"
table_name = "TMP_XML"
file_name = "xml_out.xml"
engine.cursor().execute("put file://C:/Users/Desktop/Data/" + file_name + " @PUBLIC.%TMP_XML")
full_table_name = "TMP_XML"
engine.cursor().execute("copy into {} file_format = (type = xml, compression = auto)".format(full_table_name))    I am not sure if the 2nd statement needs a different name but this works but it inserts a row with an entirely different XML document.  Should I have used a different name for full_table_name?

Comment: Ok I fixed it by adding the first line of code you put up there that I missed.  Thanks!